# populating other select drop down based on first select drop down

Tags: java, javascript, struts

I am using struts 1.2, I have a very general requirement that, I have two following dropdown box. now i want when we select the category, it should populate the subcatoegory select box. i tried with javascript but no luck is working.

please some one guide me.

I can do this by using html select.

```
 <html:select property="cat" onchange="getSubcatValue(this.value);">    
<html:option value="0">Category</html:option>
<html:optionsCollection name="PostaddForm" property="categoryList"  label="catName" value="catID"/>
</html:select>



 <html:select property="subCat" >
<html:option value="0">Category</html:option>
<html:optionsCollection name="PostaddForm" property="subCategoryList"  label="label" value="value"/>
</html:select>
```

Comment: So, what does the getSubcatValue() javascript function do? What do you think it should do?

Comment: It's hard to help without knowing what you've already tried, so post the Javascript code you wrote that didn't work (and then explain how and why it didn't work). Just saying that you didn't have any luck isn't helpful to us, we're not mind readers. Explain what you expected to happen and what actually happened.

Comment: java script is not working in this case....

Comment: @Abhishek: you need to be a bit more explicit: show us the JavaScript, tell us what you think it should do, and tell us what it does in reality (it throws an error in the JavaScript console; it doesn't throw any error, but doesn't fetch anything; it fetches a list of options but doesn't populate the select box ...) We don't have any crystal ball to tell us what's wrong in your invisible code, and we won't implement your application for you.

Comment: Yes sir thanks, actually when we will try to check the value of html select that time it will fail and  now I implemented <select> instead of <htnl select>.   now its working.....I just wanted the same using struts tag.

Comment: @Abhishek The Struts tags are interpreted on the server side, and generate valid HTML that is then passed to the browser and creates your standard SELECT DOM element on the client (browser) side which is what your Javascript interacts with.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using jQuery, it would be something like this:

```
<select id="mainDropDown" onchange="getSubcatValue()">
     //Options for mainDropDown list
</select>

<select id="subDropDown"></select>

<script type="text/javascript>
    function getSubcatValue() 
    {
        var chosenValue = $("#mainDropDown").val();
        var options = $('#subDropDown').prop('options');
        options = [];
        if (chosenValue == "something") {
            for (var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
                options[i] = new Option(i+1, i); // populate the subDropDown with 10 options: 1, 2 ,3, 4, etc... 
                //The 1st parameter is the text for the option, the 2nd parameter is the value of the option
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT:** Based on Anthony comment, I'd like to add that the for loop is just for demonstrating purpose to help you get an idea how to populate the options. In real world, for example, in my own web application, I made an Ajax call to retrieve the options data in XML to populate the drop down list.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Using jQuery is a good idea. The rest of it seems like a pretty horrendous way of doing things for anything that's not incredibly simple. His dropdowns are data-driven, so there's no guarantee he'll know all of the options to include in his Javascript or that they'll remain the same. Having to change your code because your data has changed is an awful situation to put yourself in.

Comment: @Anthony You're right! =) because I don't know how he wants to retrieve the information, I can only provide him with this much. In my web application, I get the data for the options by making an Ajax call and processing the XML result. If he'd like to do the same thing, I can help him with more code for sure ^^

Comment: yes i have tried this approach, but i wanted to use <html:select> its OK and really thanks 4 your input..